# Closed form solution for $x^n + x+ C = 0$

Tags: polynomials, closed-form

Is there a closed form solution for $x^n + x+ C = 0$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: *A lot* depends on what you mean by closed form. For example, the real root of the equation $x^5 + x - 3 = 0$ is not expressible using radicals.

Comment: Similarly, $x^7 +x + 1$ has one real root which cannot be expressed in radicals.  (Its Galois group is $S_7$.)

Comment: If you consider _generalized hypergeometric functions_ as a closed-form, then see my answer below.

Comment: There is also a closed form with quantile functions like in [formula $(1)$ here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636461/list-of-closed-form-special-cases-and-transformations-of-wolfram-language-s-inve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of the polynomial $x^5 + x + a$ can be written in terms of radicals and the [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical).  The Bring radical is necessary and is sufficient for all quintics (via a reduction first to Bring-Jerrard form).

The Bring radical is insufficient for higher degrees.  For instance, the [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) is used to solve the sextic (and almost no one would call an expression containing that function "closed").

I recall (and would entertain a reference in comments or a counterexample, since I don't have one handy) that, in degree $\geq 5$, solvable polynomials are isolated in the space of coefficients, so even if there are an $n \geq 5$ and $C$ which give a polynomial with roots in terms of radicals, there is an interval $(C - \epsilon, C + \epsilon)$ such that if $C'$ is in that interval and $C' \neq C$, then $x^n + x + C'$ does not have roots expressible in radicals.  (That is, a microscopic change in $C$ breaks the property of having roots expressible in radicals, no matter how small the change.)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the *hypergeometric function* and *generalized hypergeometric function* ${_pF_q}$ as closed-forms, then there are closed-form solutions to $x^n+x-\beta = 0\,$ for ***any*** integer $n>2$.

---

**I. n = 5**

$$z^5+z-\beta = 0$$

A root $z$ is,

$$z = \color{blue}\beta\,{_4F_3}\Big(\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45;\,\frac24,\frac34,\frac54;\,-\frac{5^5}{4^4}\beta^4\Big)$$

---

**II. n = 6**

$$z^6+z-\beta = 0$$

A root $z$ is,

$$z = \color{blue}\beta\,{_5F_4}\Big(\frac16,\frac26,\frac36,\frac46,\frac56;\,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45,\frac65;\,-\frac{6^6}{5^5}\beta^5\Big)$$

---

***And so on.***

Answer (score 0):

. Let $x=\zeta_{n-1}\bar x$, $\bar C=-\zeta_{n-1}C$, and multiply both sides by $-\zeta_{n-1}$, where $(\zeta_m)^m=-1$, to get

$$\bar x^n-\bar x-\bar C=0$$

By the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example), a series solution is given by

$$\bar x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{nk}k\frac{\bar C^{(n-1)k+1}}{(n-1)k+1}$$

In terms of the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) this is

$$\bar x=\bar C\cdot{}_nF_{n-1}\left(\frac1n,\frac2n,\dots,\frac nn;\frac2{n-1},\frac3{n-1},\dots,\frac n{n-1};\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}\bar C^{n-1}\right)$$

and hence the original solution is given by

$$x=-\zeta_{n-1}^2\cdot{}_nF_{n-1}\left(\frac1n,\frac2n,\dots,\frac nn;\frac2{n-1},\frac3{n-1},\dots,\frac n{n-1};\frac{n^n}{(1-n)^{n-1}}C^{n-1}\right)$$

As noted in the comments and other answers, this only reduces down to a reasonable closed-form in general for $n<5$. For $n=5$, the Bring radical is needed, and from there it just gets nastier.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^n+x+C=0$$

This equation is a trinomial equation. See [Szabó 2010].
$\ $

$$x+x^n+C=0$$
$$-\frac{x}{C}-\frac{x^n}{C}-1=0$$
$x\to -Ct$:
$$t-(-1)^nC^{n-1}t^n-1=0$$

Now the equation is in the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.
$\ $

[[Szabó 2010] Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[[Belkić 2019] Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)

Comment: The [_Fox-Wright function_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $_p\psi_q(z)$ generalizes even more the _generalized hypergeometric function_ $_p F_q(z)$. But $_p F_q(z)$ can already express trinomials $x^m+x^n+A=0$. What would be more interesting is a 2-parameter function that can solve quadrinomials $x^m+x^n+Ax+B=0$ but, after all these years, I still can't find any specific example of the [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) solving a sextic.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Could you ask this as a MSE question?

Comment: I’ll ask it tomorrow. Need to do something first.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII It was mentioned on Mathworld that the Kampé de Fériet function could solve a sextic among other sites, so it is intriguing that no solution was found. Also, you can use Lagrange reversion and find $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} (x^a+x^b)^n$ as the series coefficients for $1$ root via binomial series, but it is hard to get the resulting double sum into the Kampé de Fériet form due to the binomials. We could maybe get all complex solutions using a substitution like in [Glasser’s derivation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Other_characterizations)

Comment: @IV_ It is done. Kindly see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728274/4781).

Comment: @TymaGaidash I've been looking for an _explicit_ Kampé de Fériet solution to the reduced sextic for years, but haven't found one yet. I'd settle for any two-parameter function. This [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728274/4781) might be of interest.